# Creating custom function in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm trying to create a custom function that will return the percentage of a column consisting of 0 in this dataframe (refer to the image).

The interested columns are "Scholarship", "Hipertension", "Diabetes", "Alcoholism", "Handcap" and "SMS_received".

For instance, the Hipertension column consists of 70179 "0" and 18029 "1". Therefore, it is expected to return a percentage of 82.7% (70179/88208).

This is the code I wrote for it but not working.[Refer to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFJMO.png)

Comment: uncapatalize the `for`. 
Also, don't post images of code....

Comment: Be more descriptive and dont just post screenshot, but post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it simply is : `1-sum(col)/len(col)`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong at for loop. You need to correct that first.

within your function you can try getting first total count of 0's and 1's with;

```
values = df["column_name"].value_counts()
```

Then using this variable you can make your calculation and return percent. So example function would be for you;

```
def percent(column_name):
     #below will return pandas series
     values = df[column_name].value_counts(dropna=False)
     #you access and assign them to variables
     zeros= values["0"]
     ones = values["1"]
     percentage = zeros/(zeros+ones)
     return percentage
```

Comment: Thanks @Lanre

I want to use this function at many places in my code. So, I think it may not be good (as it would be repetitive) to get the value count of all the columns. Or what do you think?

Comment: Hi  @TaiwoRidwan, would be glad if you could pick my answer as best one if its usefull for you.  Well another way would be since you need only ones to calculate percentage, you would save total row number with values as a variable than calculate percentage, but that would include NA values in your calculation and i think it would be misleading.

Comment: I am still yet to get the desired answer on how to use a loop to solve the problem.